# NoSuchElementException on Codechef

Tags: java

I am trying to run code using Codechef online compiler, however it generates the error

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException at int t=input.nextInt();
```

But this code is perfectly executing on my compiler

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  
int t = input.nextInt();  
input.nextLine();
```

Comment: Please don't edit back changes I've made to avoid your question being closed! Also, consider accepting the answer if it was the right solution, so others knows it.

Answer (score 3):

Codechef apparently doesn't let you use the **input** stream by default.
You can check if the System `InputStream` is available using

```
System.out.println(System.in.available());
```

And looking if the result is `0` or not.

[image]

To submit inputs you need to tick the *Custom input* checkbox and use the textarea below.

[image]